# Create Simple Facebook application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have Created a Webpage in .NET(MVC) and uploaded to Domain(www.fbdemo.event.com).
Then Created one Facebook Application on Facebook.com named as OnlineQuestions and given 
Canvas Url= http://www.fbdemo.event.com/
Secured Canvas Url = http://www.fbdemo.event.com/

When i Visit to apps.facebook.com/onlinequestions
Gives an Error "This Connection is Untrusted"

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: This reads more like an ad than a question...

Comment: @steve p : do you want some more information of problem ?

Comment: @user1761415 Please accept the answer if your problem got solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the secured canvas url you have mentioned should start with https://

Your domain should have an ssl certificate installed, as Facebook always connects to secured canvas url.

Secondly, if you are developing for testing purpose, you should allow facebook for unsecured browsing. or use a forward service as shown here https://forwardhq.com/in-use/facebook

Comment: Thanx Mr.Shaikh Farooque And MR.Sandip, Its working perfectly after enabling SSL. Its my first app on Facebook working very nice. Thanx once again.

Answer (score 0):

Since facebook has disabled the untrusted url last year you will require the ssl for your domain.

Right now you can access your application by typing https://apps.facebook.com/onlinequestions in chrome it will prompt you for the untrusted site and after pressing continue anyway you can access your app.

But compulsorily you will require a SSL.

Comment: Thanx Mr.Shaikh Farooque and Mr.Sandip, Its working perfectly after enabling SSL. Its my first app on Facebook working very nice. Thanx once again.